# Merge two results from CTE's as separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm attempting the DataLemur [problem](https://datalemur.com/questions/laptop-mobile-viewership), in my own way but using CTE's so I can learn them better. I have the correct output, however, I need to join the results from `mobiletotal` with `laptoptotal` but each result being in a separate column with their names as `mobile_views` and `laptop_views`. How can I do that?

The best I have come up with is a `UNION ALL`, but that only gives a single column

```
with mobiletotal as (
    select count(*)
    from viewership
    group by device_type
    having device_type IN ('tablet','phone')
),    
laptoptotal as (
    select count(*)
    from viewership
    group by device_type
    having device_type = 'laptop'
)    
(select SUM(count) AS "mobile_views" from mobiletotal)
union all
(select SUM(count) AS "laptop_views" from laptoptotal)
```

Result I get is:

```
mobile_views
3
2
```

But what I need is:

```
laptop_views    mobile_views
2               3
```

Comment: Have you tried CROSS JOIN? SELECT  SUM(count) AS "mobile_views",X. "laptop_views" from mobiletotal CROSS JOIN(select SUM(count) AS "laptop_views" from laptoptotal)AS X

Comment: You need to determine what the relationship between them is. Is it a date?
Providing example DDL/DML would be very helpful. Consider: `DECLARE @Viewership TABLE (device_type NVARCHAR(50), ...); INSERT INTO @Viewership (device_type, ...) VALUES ('laptop', ...), ('tablet', ...), ('phone', ...) ... ;`

Comment: Conditional aggregation would make more sense, then there no need for two weeks/scans of the table, just a single `SELECT`  with 2  `COUNT`s.

Comment: Side note, your `HAVING` clause should really be a`WHERE`. The `HAVING` is generally used for doing aggregate boolean expressions. For example `HAVING SUM(SomeColumn) > 10`

Comment: FWIW, `CTEs` are mostly useful when you need some tabular data; even if just a single row, but multiple columns. If you're using a `CTE` to project a single scalar value, a `CTE` is not the right tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize you want to use CTE's, but this is an ideal scenario to use `conditional aggregation` and use just one table scan.

```
select
 sum(case when device_type in ('tablet','phone') then 1 else 0 end) as mobile_views, 
 sum(case when device_type in ('laptop') then 1 else 0 end) as laptop_views
from viewership
where device_type in ('tablet','phone','laptop');
```

| mobile_views | laptop_views |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7bJS14PAKqUXFx2zbMuFBg/0) In postgres, but same syntax for sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax-wise, you can do this:

```
with cte ...
select
  (select sum(count) from mobiletotal) as mobile_views,
  (select sum(count) from laptoptotal) as laptop_views
```

But you can get same results without group by:

```
with mobiletotal as (
    select count(*) as c
    from viewership
    where device_type in ('tablet', 'phone')
), laptoptotal as (
    select count(*) as c
    from viewership
    where device_type = 'laptop'
)
select
    (select c from mobiletotal) as mobile_views,
    (select c from laptoptotal) as laptop_views
```

Comment: Interesting. Why do you have a lone “select” on two subselects? Where is the missing “from”? 
I’m still learning and have never seen a select on it’s own.

Comment: `from` is not needed, at least in SQL server. `select 1` is valid SQL on its own.

Comment: If you want to use CTE to do so, this is the approach. Just select the output from your CTE as columns. No need to Union. Union stacks rows whereas select creates columns.